# Alternative to jQuery replaceAll()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-table

I have some code that removes a tr from a dynamically built table as a jQuery object (each tr has a unique id: trid):

```
tri = $("#"+trid+"");
var newrow = '<tr id="newr"><td colspan="4" align="center"><div id="nrow"> </div></td></tr>';
tri.after(newrow);
tri.detach();
```

I then put a form in the div 'nrow' using innerHTML... There's a jQuery ui datepicker in the form that works this first time.

When the form is cancelled I put the list back to the way it was:

```
setTimeout("tri.replaceAll( $('#newr') )", 400);
```

This all works beautifully, except that it kills the jquery ui datepicker in the form if I try to edit that (or any) row after that.  I've trouble shot it down to being the replaceAll line. If I take that out and replace the list by building it again it works just fine (it's not the timeout either).

So is there another way to replace the tr 'newr' with the jquery object 'tri' without using replaceAll (replaceWith doesn't work either)?

EDIT:

OK so this is how I move the form from the div elsewhere on the page:

```
eP = $('#eP');
eP.replaceAll( $('#nrow') );
$("#editPast").show('blind','',500,'');
```

eP contains the hidden div editPast...

then in the cancel function I put eP back:

```
setTimeout(function() {eP.appendTo($('#ePreplace')); }, 500);  (thanks adeneo!)
```

before I tri.replaceAll, though with the setTimeout it happens after...

So I guess my problem is that eP doesn't carry the datepicker state after it's been used in #nrow, just the html.

---

FIXED!

changed `eP.appendTo` to `$('#eP').appendTo` so that it takes it from the dom instead of the original variable.  Oops!  Thanks for making me re-think this with your `just detach()` comment!

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`

Comment: What SLaks said, and just [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the form the second time, you're already using it elsewhere. If your just switching between elements, you could maybe just hide/show them, and not remove them from the DOM.

Comment: Slaks, not the first time I've heard that, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it without putting it in quotes. If I take the quotes away it doesn't wait the 400 ms, it just does it immediately.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {tri.replaceAll( $('#newr') ) }, 400);`

Comment: @K'shin, see @adeneo 's comment, it is the correct usage of `setTimeout`. Did you learn the quote thing in w3schools.com?

Comment: adeneo, thank you!  Derek, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

changed eP.appendTo to $('#eP').appendTo so that it takes it from the dom instead of the original variable. Oops! Thanks adeneo for making me re-think this with your 'just detach()' comment!

Thanks NiftyDude for suggesting I do this too...